# Node.JS HTTPS issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeQueueSize' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I have a Node.JS HTTPS server and I'm getting randomly the following error

```
net.js:729
  if (req.async && this._handle.writeQueueSize != 0)
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeQueueSize' of null
    at TLSSocket.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:729:32)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._writev (net.js:737:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:327:12)
    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:416:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:368:7)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:824:12)
Worker 33233 died -> 33245 born.
```

I'm using multidomain in the HTTPS, but there isn't a special trigger for this issue, I just see it in the logs randomly.

```
try {
    var options = {
        SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
            if (!secureContext[domain]) {
                domain = 'default';
            }
            cb(null, tls.createSecureContext(secureContext[domain]));
        },
        key: secureContext['default'].key,
        cert: secureContext['default'].cert,
    };
    global.serverHTTPS = https.createServer(options, app);
} catch (err){
    console.error(err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
}


global.serverHTTPS.on('connection', onConnection);
global.serverHTTPS.on('error', onError);


global.serverHTTPS.listen(global.config.httpsPort);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have recently fixed the same bug. Issue was caused by destroying net.Socket in tls.Server instance. So if you need to destroy a secure connection you should listen `secureConnection` [event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_event_secureconnection).

```
try {
    var options = {
        SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
            if (!secureContext[domain]) {
                domain = 'default';
            }
            cb(null, tls.createSecureContext(secureContext[domain]));
        },
        key: secureContext['default'].key,
        cert: secureContext['default'].cert,
    };
    global.serverHTTPS = https.createServer(options, app);
} catch (err){
   console.error(err.message);
   console.error(err.stack);
}

global.serverHTTPS.on('secureConnection', onConnection);
global.serverHTTPS.on('error', onError);

global.serverHTTPS.listen(global.config.httpsPort);
```